# D3 - Buttons inside tooltip should be disabled based on selection color

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a map of the counties of the US generated via D3.  One of the events bound to each county is a click event which renders a tooltip overlay with three buttons in it.  What I want to do is disable one of the buttons based on the color of the click selection.

Currently, if I step through the click handler in Firebug, the appropriate button is disabled, but without a breakpoint enabled, all buttons are enabled regardless.

I have a module variable `thisObj` defined in part by

```
thisObj : {
  ...
  _fillColors : { 
    market : "#0000ff",
    prospect : "#ff0000",
    neutral : "#c0c0c0",
    hover : "#4CD550" 
  },
  ...
}
```

I have a HTML template set up as a module variable

```
thisObj._tooltip.template = "<div id = 'tooltip_template'>" + 
            "<div class = 'county_data'></div>" +
            "<img src = '/static/images/delete.png' width = '28' height = '28' class = 'delete_logo' id = 'close_tooltip' />" +
            "<div id = 'no_client_message'></div>" +
            "<button id = 'add_prospective_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Prospective Market</button>" +
            "<button id = 'add_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Market County</button>" +
            "<button id = 'remove_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Remove Market</button></div>";
```

Inside the click handler, I generate the tooltip DOM element and bind jQuery UI button overlays

```
//add tooltip HTML and styles to this element
thisObj._tooltip.tooltip.html(thisObj._tooltip.template)
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 50) + "px")
  .style("pointer-events" , "auto")
  .style("width", "400px")
  .style("height", "150px");

//get county name and state for future use
thisObj._currentCounty.name = d.name + ", " + d.properties.StateCode

//add in county name and state text
$(".county_data").text(thisObj._currentCounty.name);

//generate jQuery UI button overlays for the tooltip buttons, 
//and enable or disable as eccessary
$(".tooltip_button").button();
```

Then I check if a dropdown selection has been made.  If it hasn't, then all the buttons are disabled.  Otherwise, a rgb2hex function is used to convert the background color to hex and a comparison is made

```
if (thisObj._currentClient.id == null) {
  $("#no_client_message").text("No client has been selected");
  $(".tooltip_button").button("disable");
}

else {
  var countyFillColor = rgb2hex($("#" + d.id).css("fill"));

  if (countyFillColor == thisObj._fillColors.market)
    $("#add_market").button("disable");

  if (countyFillColor == thisObj._fillColors.prospect)
    $("#add_prospective_market").button("disable");
}

//fade tooltip into view
thisObj._tooltip.tooltip
  .transition()
  .duration(800)
  .style("opacity", 1);
```

My issue is that the first part of the conditional works as necessary by disabling all the buttons, but the selective disable does not work outside of stepping through in Firebug.  Time after time, when I click on a red element, I see `add_prospective_market` button disabled after manually clicking through the lines in Firebug, but removing the breakpoint results in all buttons enabled.

Comment: You haven't shown us your complete code, but it sounds like the function to enable/disable buttons is executed several times in different states. Thus, the first time it is executed, everything works, but a subsequent execution changes that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I put the module code at http://pastebin.com/UEjKbTWp.  If there are several state values that are overwriting each other, how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Ok, that's a lot of code. Have you tried stepping further in the debugger to see what changes the state afterwards?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Well, the relevant code sections are between lines 329 and 380, then it returns back to the D3 codebase.  When I step through the last line in the debugger, the enable/disable state is set, so I think it may have to do with the button setting code block getting skipped over due to the D3 event precedence.